# Java builder pattern - changing the state of a referenced object

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

If I am passing mutable objects references ( say a Map or a List or some object with setters ) to a builder to create a complex object, the state of already built object could easily be changed if I am call mutation methods directly on the referenced objects.

Eg;

```
public final class Foo {
   private final String name;
   private final ArrayList hobbies;

   ...

   
   public static class Builder {
      private final String name;
      private final ArrayList hobbies;

      ...
      
      public Foo build() {
          return new Foo(name, hobbies);
      }


   }
}

ArrayList hobbies = new ArrayList();
hobbies.add("painting");
hobbies.add("singing");

Foo f = new Foo.Builder().setName("test").setHobbies(hobbies).build();

hobbies.add("playing");
```

State of object instance f built by builder has changed since the internal field is updated.  If this is not desirable it can easily fixed by deep copy or by exposing methods to add one hobby at a time.

Is this kind of behavior for builder pattern acceptable ? or is it recommended to keep everything immutable ?

Comment: clone the objects

Comment: Don't set hobbies, have methods `addHobby(String hobby)`, which will add to the arraylist, and `addHobbies(List hobbies)`, which will add provided hobbies to the list

Comment: @Chaosfire that might work for arrays or maps or some complex objects. Lets say if you are setting a httpconnection factory object with timeouts already initialized (and few other settings) along with a DB connection pool etc then you would still change the settings of these objects directly.  Like other poster mentioned, its not a violation of builder pattern if use case requires it. So, I guess its still okay to use the pattern for use cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple, single answer to your quesion because it depends on the object to build and its relationships to the objects of which it is built, completely.

If the "parts" are intended to be immutable: don't make them mutable or encapsulate them so that they can't be modified after the object has been built. In your example, `name` is immutable, so it's fine. You can encapsulate the mutable list `hobbies` like user Chaosfire suggested.

On the other hand there are use cases where you want the parts of an object to be mutable (despite the use of the builder pattern). Think of GUIs for example. There you add components to some parent component but still want to access/modify them. There's no need for a builder to clone components to make them immutable.

It's not the builder who defines the rules but your object model and the builder has to follow.